# Can a cycloidal pendulum be extended to make a full swing?

Tags: classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

A [cycloidal pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycloid#Cycloidal_pendulum) is isochrone, meaning it's period is independent of it's amplitude. But a cycloidal pendulum - as usually depicted - doesn't do a full 360 degrees swing. Why is that? Is there a limit on how high a pendulum can swing, so that it is still isochrone? Or is it possible to build a isochrone pendulum that does a full 360 degrees swing? And if so, what kind of curve would it need to follow? Is it just an extension of a cycloid as shown in the picture below.

[image]

Or would a 360 degree isochrone pendulum maybe follow a different curve, e.g. maybe something like a [Cardioid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardioid)?

Comment: Isn't the upper limits unreachable due to boundary conditions?

Comment: I don't understand the close votes on this one. It's a perfectly reasonable, and perfectly clear, question: given a time period $T$, is there an upper bound to the maximal velocity that an isochronal gravity-powered pendulum can achieve? The standard construction suggests that there is, but it is not a trivial question at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sketch became too long to be a comment so I will post it as an answer anyway.

Let us say we have a wire forming a cycloid in the vertical plane as in the figure bellow

[image]

A friction-less bead into this wire will oscillate with known period $T$ independently of its releasing point. Assume we can symmetrically continue the wire above the dashed line. If we release the bead from $A'$, which is infinitesimally close to $A$ but above the dashed line, then it will take a time $\Delta t_{AB}<T$ to complete the segment ${AB}+BA$ since it travels faster. If we want the same period $T$ for the bead to oscillate between $A'$ and $B'$, then the time taken along $A'A$ shall be $d t_{A'A}=(T-\Delta t_{AB})/2$. The idea is to use energy conservation and the parametric equation of the cycloid to compute $\Delta t_{AB}$ and then obtain $d t_{A'A}$.The last step is to suitably chose the slope of the straight segment $A'A$ so that the interval $dt$ for the bead to slide from $A'$ to $A$ matches  $dt_{A'A}$. I think you will find that $dt_{A'A}<dt$ even when $A'$ is vertically above $A$ (which gives the least $dt$). This means that the tautochrone curve cannot be continued above the dashed line. You can also recall that this construction can be actually used to [obtain the tautochrone](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/346683/intuition-why-does-the-period-not-depend-on-the-amplitude-in-a-pendulum/346733#346733). The slope of the infinitesimal segments are always increasing, from zero at $C$ to $\pi/2$ at $B$. One increment further and we can no longer increase the slope.