# Why is pendulum isochronic?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, time, harmonic-oscillator, anharmonic-oscillators

We all know that the pendulum is isochronic, i.e. that it takes the same time regardless of the amplitude is this is less than 20 degrees.

But how do we prove it mathematically?
What happens when the amplitude grows that breaks this law?

I am not looking for the intuition, but the math behind it, and I would like to see explicitly how larger amplitudes break the isochronicity, so this is different from the other questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does a simple pendulum or a spring-mass system show simple harmonic motion only for small amplitudes?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/313673/)

Comment: Also relevant: [Intuition - why does the period not depend on the amplitude in a pendulum?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/346683/)

Comment: @Chris The question you suggest explicitly says: "I know the math of the problem. I am looking for physical intuition". I am asking exactly the opposite question.

Comment: That's the second question I linked, and why I referenced it as "relevant" rather than a duplicate. The first question is definitely a duplicate.

Comment: @Chris I don't think the other question is a duplicate either, unless, it is possible, I don't understand it. I would like to know exactly what breaks isochronicity as the amplitude grows

Comment: What breaks isochronicity is that $\sin\theta\neq\theta$ for angles that are too large.

Comment: The pendulum is not exactly isochronous, so nothing “breaks isochronicity” as this is not a property of the system to start with.  What *makes* the pendulum *approximately* isochronous is the truncation associated with the small angle approximation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The math behind it is in the restoring force:

$$ F = mg\sin{\theta} = mg(\theta - \frac 1 3 \theta^3 + \cdots )$$

For small displacement, you only keep $\theta$, which gives the isochronic simple harmonic oscillator. For larger $\theta$ the cubic term means there's not enough restoring force to get back in time to maintain the SHO frequency.

When you get to $\theta = \pi $, well, you're stuck. Sort of.